# python ftplib.error_perm 550 : no such file, but only with absolute path

Tags: python, relative-path, ftplib

I have a little `python` code to upload some `gifs` to a FTP server. Code works well when my script is in my `gif dir` and when I use something like `img = "name.gif"`.

But as soon as I want to use absolute path like below:

`img = "/home/pi/photobooth/gif/name.gif"`

I get a 550 error_perm telling me `/home/pi/photobooth/gif/name.gif: no such file or directory`

*Does anyone know why ?*

My code is mentioned below:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import sys

def ULimg(img):
    host = 'host.com'
    user = 'user'
    passwd = 'pass'

    try:
        ftp = FTP(host)
        ftp.set_pasv(False)
        ftp.login(user, passwd)
    except:
        print('Error connecting to FTP server')
        sys.exit()

    file = open(img, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + img, file)
    file.close()
    ftp.quit()

img = '/home/pi/photobooth/gif/name.gif'
ULimg(img)
```

And here is the `error` I get when I use absolute path :

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/pi/photobooth/pics/gif/UL.py", line 34, in <module> ULimg(img)

File "/home/pi/photobooth/pics/gif/UL.py", line 22, in ULimg
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + img, file)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 471, in storbinary
conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 358, in ntransfercmd
resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
return self.getresp()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
raise error_perm, resp   error_perm: 550 /home/pi/photobooth/pics/gif/name.gif: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

*Thanks if anyone can help !*

Comment: Probably the server only permits paths relative to some configuration-defined root directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not even know that servers could have limits and permissions about paths on the sending machine ! Is there a way to bypass this problem ? I guess I could copy the files to the working directory, upload them, then erase them, but I guess it would need some little more time (I can have big and numerous gifs), so it's not efficient for me…

Comment: You might be better off asking about this on superuser.com - I don't think it's really on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks again snakecharmerb. Sorry if it's off-topic, I often read threads here but it's my first question. But if it's really off-topic, I don't get why ! Isn't it pure python question, trying to know why my code doesn't work and how to fix it (coding, not change server's conf) ?